# How to prevent outside JavaScript event handlers from being triggered from a Shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom

I am trying to create a Chrome extension that is toggled via keyboard shortcut. The keyboard shortcut brings up a ShadowDOM that contains a search bar (similar to spotlight search). The problem I am getting is some key presses (e.g. the key 's' on GitHub) will trigger a javascript action on the native webpage (in this case, selecting GitHub's own search bar).

Does anyone know of a way to disable outside JavaScript events, and/or a way to do this via Chrome Extension?

Comment: `containerElem.contentEditable = true` and `containerElem.addEventListener('keydown', e => !e.altKey && !e.metaKey && e.stopPropagation(), true);`